# Why stored procedure not updating data in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following stored procedure and I read data in `datagridview` and some data outside `datagridview` (master and details ).

Its laboratory result , the header data  was patient information and request information the data in datagridview is the result details:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[UPDATE_PARA_RESULTS]
@ORDER_ID int,
@NORMAL_RESULT varchar(10),
@SAMPLE_STATUS int,
@RESULT_NOTE  varchar(200),
@APPROVED_BY varchar(50),
@APPROVED_DATE datetime, 
@TESTID int,
@SERIAL int,
@TEXT varchar(50),
@VALUE varchar(50)

AS

UPDATE [dbo].[LAB_PARA_RESULTS]
   SET [ORDER_ID] = @ORDER_ID
       ,[NORMAL_RESULT] = @NORMAL_RESULT
       ,[SAMPLE_STATUS] = @SAMPLE_STATUS
       ,[RESULT_NOTE] = @RESULT_NOTE
       ,[APPROVED_BY] = @APPROVED_BY
       ,[APPROVED_DATE] = @APPROVED_DATE
       ,[VALUE] = @VALUE

where ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID
and   TESTID   = @TESTID
and SERIAL = @SERIAL
```

when I save data the header details saved to the database but the data in `datagrid` view not saved in the database.

Another thing the data in `datagridview` coming from lab specialist window inserted first by them, the last step approve the result if there is any modifications or change I update it by using this stored procedure.

The VALUE field in `datagridview` not updated the other columns outside `datagridview` updated.
This is the save button void :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (radyes.Checked == true)
    {
        checknormal = 1;
    }
    if (RADNO.Checked == true)
    {
        checknormal = 2;
    }
    if (checkApproveResult.Checked == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            result.INSERT_PARA_RESULTS(Convert.ToInt32(txtsample.Text),
                                       Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text), 
                                       Convert.ToInt32(txtTestId.Text),
                                      checknormal.ToString(),
                                      5,
                                      txtExamUser.Text,
                                      DateTime.Parse(DateTimeExamined.Value.ToString()),
                                      Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                                      "",                                    
                                      8,
                                      Convert.ToInt32(txtDept.Text),
                                      Convert.ToInt32(txtPno.Text),
                                      Convert.ToInt32(txtcustid.Text),
                                      txtReqForm.Text);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Result Saved Successfully ", "Entering Para Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            result.UPDATE_PARA_RESULTS(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
                                      checknormal.ToString(),
                                      6,
                                      "",
                                      txtApprovedby.Text,
                                      DateTime.Parse(dateTimeApprove.Value.ToString()),
                                      Convert.ToInt32(txtTestId.Text),
                                      Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells["SERIAL"].Value),
                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells["TEXT"].Value.ToString(),
                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells["RESULT"].Value.ToString());

        }

        result.update_sample_status(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text));
        MessageBox.Show("Result Approved Successfully ", "Approve Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is this statement backwards: checkApproveResult.Checked == false

Comment: There's no code here that calls the stored procedure. Could that be why nothing is getting updated?

Comment: @jdweng: checkapprovedresult is checkbox if checked then executes the code otherwise go to code after else statement

Comment: @scott : the code available down after else statement scroll down and you will find it (result.UPDATE_PARA_RESULTS).

Comment: checkapprovedresults sound like you are going to write to the database.  But then the true/false is reversed.  When not checked you are writing and checked you are reading.

Comment: @jdweng there is 2 phase if checkbox (checkapproveresult.checked == false then insert the result ) and second phase if the checkbox.checked==true then only approve the result and call the procedure UPDATE_PARA_RESULTS  in first phase i am inserting the first result in second phase i am updating the result if there is any changes.